# Command line interface/tool for Mountain Lion's dictation app?

Tags: macos, applescript, speech-recognition, osx-mountain-lion, text-to-speech

Lots of people know about the Mac OS X command line tool `say`, which performs text-to-speech on a Mac from the terminal:

`sh $ say Hello World!`

Is there a command-line tool available for the Mountain Lion dictation application -- something that does speech-to-text?

Apple documentation doesn't seem to mention anything, but I wouldn't be surprised either if there is an undocumented CLI for the Dictation service hidden somewhere in OS X.

Comment: It's rumoured to be in OS X 10.9.

Comment: Alternatively, what about a way to control the Dictation app via AppleScript (which could then be executed from the command line)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to invoke the `SpeechApplicationServer.app`, using AppleScript. More details here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127366/speechrecognitionserver-not-found-in-mavericks-with-applescript